# .htaccess - Read all sub-directories and files by one file

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to add a .htaccess file into domain.com/links/ so if anyone goes to domain.com/links/mylink/ or domain.com/links/mylink it is passed to domain.com/links/link.php?link=xxxxx but I just can't seem to find the RewriteRule that doesn't keep repeating itself.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /links/link.php?link=$1 [L]
```

The above does the following
domain.com/links/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/something

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# If file exists, don't rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite everything to link.php
RewriteRule . /links/link.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.